# how to save login on mobile device application built with html5

Tags: html, mobile

If I build an application for a mobile device using HTML5 that requires the user to login, is there a way to let them save their credentials so they don't need to enter it every time?

I think it's possible with something called localstorage, but I haven't really checked into it yet.

A nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks.